# Don't get a Map correctly transformed in Dart

Tags: arrays, dart, dictionary, transformation

Should be a basic method, but even after checking many Q&As and experimenting for quite a while, I don't get it working.

I want to generate a `Map<String, bool>` from a list of objects that contain a String and a bool, each.

If I do a transformation on an existing map, everything works fine (`firstT`in the code/output below). However, with a list of objects as an input, the transformation result `second1` does not look like expected (compared with `firstT`). `second2` and `third1` result in script errors during run time - not before.

How do I get my expected result and why do my methods do not work?

```dart
void main() {
  
  final Map<Object, Object> first = <Object, Object>{'a': true, 'b': false};
  final Map<String, String> firstT = Map<String, String>.of(first.map((l,r) 
      => MapEntry(l.toString(), r.toString())));
  print ("$first - $firstT"); 
  
  final abc = [[ABC("a", true), ABC("b", true)],[ABC("a", false), ABC("b", false)]];
  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> second1 = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.fromIterable(abc[0].map((a) 
      => MapEntry(a.id, a.isit)));
  print("$second1");

  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> third1 = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(abc[0].map((a) 
    {print("${a.id} ${a.isit}");
     return MapEntry("a.id", true);
    }) as Map );  
  print ("$third1"); 

  final Map<String, bool> second2 = Map<String, bool>.fromIterable(abc[0].map((a) 
      => MapEntry(a.id, a.isit)));
  print("$second2");
}

class ABC {
  ABC(this.id, this.isit);
  final String id;
  final bool isit;
}
```

OUTPUT

```dart
{a: true, b: false} - {a: true, b: false}
{MapEntry(a: true): MapEntry(a: true), MapEntry(b: true): MapEntry(b: true)}
Script error.
```

Comment: You say you want to transform a list of objects, but then your `second1`/`second2`/`third1` attempts all try to transform `abc`, a list of *lists* of objects (and unconditionally use `abc[0]`), so it's unclear what output you expect.  Personally I'd just use [collection-`for`](https://dart.dev/language/collections#control-flow-operators) with a `Map` literal, which I think is much easier to read and reason about.

Comment: That is, why is `abc` a list of lists if you're using only `abc[0]` and ignoring `abc[1]`?

Comment: `second`/`third` were just different attempts to get it running / identifying issues. Sorry, I left the confusing `abc[0]` in the snippet. That belongs to the real life code where I extract a list from a parent list.

Comment: Anyway, you could just do:   `var map = {for (var obj in abc[0]) obj.id: obj.isit};`

Answer (score 0):

Just "discovered" a new method - `fromEntries`

This seems to do the job, to convert a list of objects into a map

```
final Map<String, bool> second3 = Map<String, bool>.fromEntries(abc[0].map((a) 
  => MapEntry(a.id, a.isit)));
```

And here the easier to read version of @jamesdlin from the comments

```
final Map<String, bool> second2 = 
   {for (final obj in abc[0]) obj.id: obj.isit};
```

I leave the question in case it helps someone else with this problem